# Country drop down is empty magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, plugin, countries

I have set default country as UK in admin, after the configuration is done, In checkout one empty drop down is showing before the UK country.

so I have used below plugin to remove that empty dropdown.

di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection">
    <plugin name="country_empty_dropdowns" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Country\Collection" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

Collection.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Country;


class Collection
{
/**
 * Arguments processing.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject
 * @param bool $emptyLabel
 *
 * @return bool|array
 */
public function beforeToOptionArray(
     \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject,
    $emptyLabel = null
) {
    return is_null($emptyLabel) ? [''] : null;
  }
}
```

Seems code is correct, but still i can see empty dropdown before the default country in checkout as well as in cart page.

Please anyone look into it and update your thoughts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After plugin is worked for me.

Below is the full code.

```
class Collection
{
/**
 * Arguments processing.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject
 * @param bool $emptyLabel
 *
 * @return bool|array
 */
public function afterToOptionArray(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection $subject,
    $options
) {
    $result = array_filter($options, function ($option) {
        return empty($option['value']) ? false : true;
     });
     return $result;
 }
}
```